# How to reinstall the default Ubuntu "20.04" graphical driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, amd-graphics

I messed up my graphic driver after trying to install "AMDGPU-PRO" OpenCL following this [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/install-opencl-for-the-amdgpu-open-source-drivers-on-debian-and-ubuntu)

[(My Picture here) My center screen is Off and 2 other screens are mirror.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWZuy.jpg)

Even when I uninstalled these drivers I'm still stuck with the same problem.

I have "no additional driver available", so how can I reinstall or reset my old driver.Even better how can I install a new ATI driver for "20.04"
[(My Picture here) no additional driver available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KUcK.png)

I have an ATI Radeon R7
[(My Picture here) Ati Radeon R7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXR4Z.png)

Thank you for your time friend!

Comment: I just reinstalled Ubuntu over it. Make sure you backup your /var/lib/mysql before